# Setting colnames in R's cpp11

Tags: r, r-lib-cpp11

Provided that cpp11 does not provide any "sugar", we need to use attributes.

I am trying to set colnames in a C++ function, as in the next MWE

```cpp
#include "cpp11.hpp"
using namespace cpp11;

// THIS WORKS
[[cpp11::register]]
doubles cpp_names(writable::doubles X) {
    X.attr("names") = {"a","b"};
    return X;
}

// THIS WON'T
[[cpp11::register]]
doubles_matrix<> cpp_colnames(writable::doubles_matrix<> X) {
    X.attr("dimnames") = list(NULL, {"A","B"});
    return X;
}
```

How can I pass a list with two vectors, one NULL and the other ("a","b"), that can be correctly converted to a SEXP?

In Rcpp, one would do `colnames(X) = {"a","b"}`.

My approach can be wrong.

Comment: Create a matrix with row- and colnames and run `attributes()` on it: you see that it is just a vector (with a `dim` attribute) along with a `dimnames` attribute that is a list of two character vectors for row and colnames.  `Rcpp` is user-friendly here and gives you an accessor helper, if you want to use something else you may have to write such a helper.

Comment: Oh, and as a follow-up, you question title is not correct.  Nobody uses `colnames` from R, it really is just a matter of setting the attribute(s) at the C API level.  Which can be done in C but is tedious -- it is much easier with proper abstractions.  Lastly, you may get this question closed on you as it doesn't really conform to the format StackOverflow prefers.

Comment: Attribute access with `cpp11` is documented at https://cpp11.r-lib.org/articles/cpp11.html#attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibly a bug with the `matrix` class s.t. attributes cannot be set. One workaround is to 'upcast' it to a `sexp` and set the attributes via that interface.

Two other notes about your MWE:

1. Initialising an item in a list with `NULL` throws an error; instead use `R_NilValue` which is R's 'NULL' expression.
2. The MWE copies the original object and modifies the copy (see cpp11's copy-on-write semantics ["Copy-on-write semantics" in the cpp11 "Motivations" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cpp11/vignettes/motivations.html#copy-on-write-semantics)); this may not be your intention with the function.

If you do not wish to modify the column names of the original object, then the following code is a correct implementation of the MWE:

```cpp
#include "cpp11.hpp"

using namespace cpp11;

[[cpp11::register]]
sexp cpp_colnames(writable::doubles_matrix<> X) {
    sexp X_sexp(X.data());
    X_sexp.attr("dimnames") = writable::list(
        { R_NilValue, writable::strings({"A", "B"}) }
    );
    return X_sexp;
}
// > X <- matrix(as.numeric(1:4), nrow=2)
// > cpp_colnames(X)
//      A B
// [1,] 1 3
// [2,] 2 4
// > X
//      [,1] [,2]
// [1,]    1    3
// [2,]    2    4
```

Otherwise, if you *do* want to modify the original object (see ["How do I modify a vector in place?" in the cpp11 FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cpp11/vignettes/FAQ.html)) then:

```cpp
#include "cpp11.hpp"

using namespace cpp11;

[[cpp11::register]]
void cpp_colnames(sexp X_sexp) {
    X_sexp.attr("dimnames") = writable::list(
        { R_NilValue, writable::strings({"A", "B"}) }
    );
}
// > X <- matrix(as.numeric(1:4), nrow=2))
// > cpp_colnames(X)
// > X
//      A B
// [1,] 1 3
// [2,] 2 4
```